# How to use an AWS Lambda Java function to call a third party REST API?

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to know how the AWS API Gateway calls third party REST APIs using authorization.

Also, how can I write an AWS Lambda Java function that will call multiple third party REST APIs and merge responses which will send to API Gateway?

Comment: It's just normal code -- call the 3rd-party API how you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway provides three kinds of Authorizers today:

- [IAM auth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) - Use policies to provide permissions to roles and users within your AWS account.
- [Custom Authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) - Call a Lambda function which handles authorization.
- [Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) - Authorize members of a Cognito User Pool to access your API.

You can setup an [HTTP integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html) which calls the third-party APIs and authorize calls using one of the above.

Thanks!
Ritisha